# How can I get the UI SynchronizationContext from a non UI thread and without forms or any object created by UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm on a non UI thread and I need to create and display a SaveDialog. But when I try to Show it: .ShowDialog() I'm getting:

> "An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Threading.ThreadStateException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll"

I have no object created at the UI, so how can I invoke this SaveDialog at the UI thread? Is there a global UI SynchronizationContext that I can use?

EDIT: I know how to do it if I have a form/control object to call the invoke/begininvoke. Or use the SynchronizationContext.Current reference at the UI thread. But I don't have any of this.

Comment: Why do you think it involves `SynchronizationContext` here? I think the problem is your `Thread`, you have to do something with it before calling `Start()`.

Comment: If you want to execute a delegate on another thread (like when you want to update a UI control from a background thread), you have to have a mechanism that posts this to the message queue of the UI thread. In .NET, this is the concept of the `SynchronizationContext`. Read more about this topic here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx

Another option might be to use asynchronous programming with the `async` and `await` keywords if your are using .NET 4.0 or 4.5. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

In .NET, you would use the `SynchronizationContext` class and pass an instance of it to your method, maybe somewhat like this.

```
public void DoSomeStuffOnBackgroundThread(SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext)
{
    // Do some stuff here
    // ...

    // Show the dialog on the UI thread
    var dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    synchronizationContext.Send(() => dialog.Show());

    // Send is performed synchronously, thus this line of code only executes when the dialog was closed. You can extract the file name here
    var fileName = dialog.FileName;
}
```

The synchronization context is built when the windows forms framework is started. Thus when your application and the UI message loop has started up, simply call `SynchronizationContext.Current` on the UI thread to obtain the instance that you can pass to methods or objects.

Finally, I definitely recommend to encapsulate this functionality behind an interface and one class that implements this interface gets a reference to the synchronization context. Thus your production code is not poluted with these unnecessary details like thread affinity.

If you have questions, please feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you feO2x, but the problem is that the thread have no reference to the UI. I was wondering if there was some global variable containing the UI SynchronizationContext.

Comment: How do you create your thread? Do you use one from the thread pool? Or do you Thread class or the Tasks Parallel Library? In any case, when you start your operation, just pass in the `SynchronizationContext`, either to a class constructor or the method that is called on the non-UI thread. It is not about obtaining the `SynchronizationContext` when you need it, but rather setting all things up at the beginning so that you can easily access it. The pattern behind this is Inversion of Control / Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 2):

The way that I handle this is by passing the UI thread's `TaskScheduler` into the object that's going to be running on a background thread. Then, anytime the background thread needs to make something happen on the UI thread, I use `Task.Factory.StartNew()` using the `TaskScheduler` that I gave to the object. To illustrate:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class BackgroundThread {
    IView _view;
    TaskScheduler _uiThreadScheduler;

    // This object is constructed on the main thread. The main thread's TaskScheduler
    // can be acquired with TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    public BackgroundThread(IView view, TaskScheduler uiThreadScheduler){
        this._view = view;
        this._uiThreadScheduler = uiThreadScheduler;
    }

    public void DoWork(){
        // Code in this function executes on a background thread
        //...
        string filename;
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            filename = _view.GetSaveFilename();
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _uiThreadScheduler);

        task.Wait();

        // filename now has input from the user, or is null
    }

}
```

By hiding the UI's implementation behind the `IView` interface, the background thread is not dependent on any particular UI implementation.